# Building an object on the fly and inject a variable

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JavaScript method that should do:

1. Create an object of a type that has been passed as first argument,
2. put a variable into that new object and
3. call the method __construct of that object and pass the arguments to it passed to this method (except for the first).

Example usage:

```
this.create('Foo', 'bar', 42);
```

Should do:

```
var O = new Foo;
Foo.Application = this;
Foo.__construct('bar', 42);
```

What I have now:

```
Application.prototype.create = function(sType)
{
    var Self = this;
    eval('var Object = new ' + sType + ';');

    // what to write here?

    var aParameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    Object.__construct.apply(aParameters);
}
```

I tried to inject the Application var into the new object with the following codes:

```
Object.Application = this;
```

or:

```
var Self = this;
$.extend(Object, { Application: eval(Self) });
```

But in the __construct method this.Application is still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You do the sensible thing and change the API to accept a constructor function instead of a string.

`app.create(Foo, args, moreargs);`

```
Application.prototype.create = function _create(klass) {
  var o = new klass();
  o.Application = this;
  o.__construct.apply(o, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
```

The reason why your code is broken is because your a) using `eval`. Don't do that.

And you b) thought `Object` was a good variable name when we have a global object constructor called `Object`.

Comment: Thank you. Without the eval() I get the error sType is no constructor (but its value is Model and new Model(); works without error). My mistake was that I put the arguments as first (and only) parameter ti the apply method. It works with Object as variable name. Why shouldn't I use this? When I define var Object, then all operations on Object wouldn't change any Object defined in another namespace, I thought. Is that not correct?

Comment: @stofl that is fine. Object is still a frustrating and confusing variable name.